# DecodeStream throwing null while storing in bitmap

Tags: java, android

This is my code... I am getting exception NULL  at `imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2,null, options);`

First time it can decode but why now, decodeStream throwing null ?

```
 public void showImageThumb(FileInputStream is)
        {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 100;
            FileInputStream is2 = is;
            BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null, options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int height = options.outHeight;
            int width = options.outWidth;
            int scale = 1;
            if ( height > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || width > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) 
            {
                 scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(options.outHeight, options.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
            }
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = scale*2;
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2,null, options);
            height = options.outHeight;
            width = options.outWidth;
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //ERROR HERE 
            imageSelectedThumb = baos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get a nullpointer exception because you are copying the

> is

**reference** in

> is2

so when you close is, you are closing is2 too. Instead of assing is to is2 you have to create a new `InpustStream`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a deep copy of InputStream Object.**Source Code** in details ,please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797510/952386

Comment: If that perfectly answers the question here, you might want to flag this question as a duplicate instead.