# decodeStream returns null

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image

I'm trying to adopt [bitmap resizing](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) tutorial - the only difference is that I use decodeStream instead of decodeResource. It's strange but decodeStream, without any manipulations, gives me a bitmap obj, but when I go through decodeSampledBitmapFromStream it returns null for some reason.
How do I fix it ?

Here's the code I use:

```
protected Handler _onPromoBlocksLoad = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
            PromoBlocksContainer c = (PromoBlocksContainer) _promoBlocksFactory.getResponse();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(c.getPromoBlocks().get(0).getSmallThumbnail());

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            InputStream stream;
            ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.banner);
            try {
                stream = request.getStream();

                //v.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)); Works fine
                Bitmap img = decodeSampledBitmapFromStream(stream, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
                v.setImageBitmap(img);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromStream(InputStream res, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(res, null, options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap img =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(res, null, options); // Gives  null 
        return img;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that once you've used an InputStream from a HttpUrlConnection, **you can't rewind and use the same InputStream again**. Therefore you have to create a new InputStream for the actual sampling of the image. Otherwise we have to abort the http request.

```
request.abort();
```

Answer (score 7):

Because the InputStream Object can only be consumed once, you have to make a deep copy of an InputStream Object when you want to resize the bitmap from inputStream of HttpUrlConnection,otherwise **decodeStream** will returns null.Here is one possible solution:

```
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
         InputStream in = null;
         InputStream in2 = null;
         try {
             final URL imgUrl = new URL(url);
             urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) imgUrl.openConnection();
             in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

             ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             copy(in,out);
             in2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

             // resize the bitmap
             bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream(in,in2);                

         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e(TAG, "Error in down and process Bitmap - " + e);
         } finally {
             if (urlConnection != null) {
                 urlConnection.disconnect();
             }
             try {
                 if (in != null) {
                     in.close();
                 }
                 if (in2 != null){
                     in2.close();
                 }
             } catch (final IOException e) {
             Log.e(TAG, "Error in when close the inputstream." + e);
             }
         }
     }
```

the souce code of Method **copy** is as follows:

```
public static int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException{

     byte[] buffer = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];

     int count = 0;

     int n = 0;

     while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {

         output.write(buffer, 0, n);

         count += n;

     }

     return count;
 }
```

the souce code of Method **decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream** is as follows:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream(InputStream in,
InputStream copyOfin, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(copyOfin, null, options);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, getting this issue when decoding a stream read from my app's private storeage on disk.  However, instead of copy, I just open the file for reading twice, and pass both streams to decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream.  I.e. no need for copy().  Thanks I was stuck with this for too long!

Comment: hello,I was also facing the same problem and tried the solution given in the post, when I tested in few device it works on some device but for some device with low heap size it again gives me outofmemory error. I dont know what to do know.. Please help.

Comment: What is IO_BUFFER_SIZE ?

Comment: Thanks. You save my day.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in the replies of the second floor.  Because in the Method of `copy()`, `inputstream` has been used，so in the method of `decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream（in，copyOfIn）`，we can not catch the value of `options.outWidth`.

Here I did some correction；We can convert each other between `byte[]` and `inputstream`  So，we can convert `inputstream` to `byte[]`, This can be used multiple times.

Code as follows：

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
InputStream inputStream = null;
InputStream copyiInputStream1 = null;
InputStream copyiInputStream2 = null;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try {
     URL url=new URL(imageUrl);
     connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);//设置连接超时
     inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
     byte[] data = InputStreamTOByte(inputStream);
     try {
          copyiInputStream1 = byteTOInputStream(data);
          copyiInputStream2 = byteTOInputStream(data);
     } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream(copyiInputStream1,copyiInputStream2);
 /** 
 * 将InputStream转换成byte数组 
 * @param in InputStream 
 * @return byte[] 
 * @throws IOException 
 */  
public byte[] InputStreamTOByte(InputStream in) throws IOException{  

    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    byte[] data = new byte[1024*16];  
    int count = -1;  
    while((count = in.read(data,0,1024*16)) != -1)  
        outStream.write(data, 0, count);  

    data = null;  
    return outStream.toByteArray();  
}  

/**
 * 将byte数组转换成InputStream
 * @param in
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public InputStream byteTOInputStream(byte[] in) throws Exception{  

    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(in);  
    return is;  
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Complete solution for getting width and height.