# BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null, when downloading a image form web

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to download a image from a URL, using the [Google Example Page](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap). I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730520/decodestream-returns-null) when I use a InputStream in the BitmapFactory.decodeStream method, I can't use twice. I'm trying to do that, but it doesn't work 'cause it returns null in the decoded image, and I don't know what I can do.

This is my code:

This part is in a doInBackground method in a AsyncTask class

```
Bitmap bitmapImage;
URL imageUrl = null;
try {
imageUrl = new URL(url[0]);

HttpGet httpRequest = null;
httpRequest = new HttpGet(imageUrl.toURI());

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

    bitmapImage = CommonMethods.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(instream, thumb_width, thumb_width);

instream.close();
return bitmapImage;

 } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
 }


 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(InputStream instream,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws IOException {

    //Copy instream for decode twice 
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    copy(instream,out);
    ByteArrayInputStream instream2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream, null, options);
    instream2.close();

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream, null, options);
 }

 public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

     // Raw height and width of image
     final int height = options.outHeight;
     final int width = options.outWidth;
     int inSampleSize = 1;

     if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
         if (width > height) {
         inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
     } else {
             inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
     }
     }

     return inSampleSize;
}

//Copy instream method
public static void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException{

     byte[] buffer = new byte[Constants.IO_BUFFER_SIZE];

 int n = 0;

 while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {

     output.write(buffer, 0, n);
 }
 }
```

Comment: can u give the image url

Comment: it's a fickr image: http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8063/8246896289_6ec6575ff4_q.jpg

Comment: I will work on this and get back to you with working code. have patience

Comment: @beni See my answer it will solve your problem.

Comment: I know this old but this is a kind of bug pleas refer it here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the code which will work for you

```
final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    //options.inSampleSize = 2;
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
                    return bitmap;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
```

Please replace the proper variable and if you wanted to scale the image you can scale it after getting the bitmap.

Comment: I've tested the others solutions and don't work. I'll try to do this in other form, but now, I prefer this solution. Scale the images after decode them., and use a weakreference in the decoded bitmap, like this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html.

Answer (score 6):

BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null because the inputstream is used twice, I've not tried your code, but it seams OK, or maybe I'm wrong.
Anyway, I've a better solution. Just use BufferedInputStream to wrap the inputStream, and before your second read, call "reset" first. Note ordinary inputStreams donnot support "reset", you may call it but nothing will happen.
My code:

```
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromStream(InputStream inputStream,
                                                   int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
                             throws IOException {
    if (!widthHeightCheck(reqWidth, reqHeight)) 
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    if (!(inputStream instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    }
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Rect rect = new Rect(-1, -1, -1, -1);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, rect, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    inputStream.reset();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, rect, options);
}
```

Comment: As it stands this should throw an `IOException` at `inputStream.reset()` unless you call `mark()` beforehand. See https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#reset().

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by wrapping the stream you get from the httpEntity in a custom WrappedStream. This WrappedStream will feed a second input stream while reading the original stream. (this is done with PipedStream)

After getting the image size with this code :

```
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
WrappedStream wrappedStream = new WrappedStream(instream);
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(wrappedStream, null, options);
```

You can call

```
InputStream reReadStream = wrappedStream.getReReadStream();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(reReadStream, null, options);
```

And finally, here is the implementation of WrappedStream (it simply delegates all calls to the wrapped inputStream, and writes all bytes that are read (or skipped) in a pipedOutputStream)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;

/** Simple class wrapping an InputStream and feeding a secondary InputStream
 *  to re-read the data that was originally available in the inputStream.
**/

public class WrappedStream extends InputStream {

private InputStream urlStream;
private PipedOutputStream pipedStream;

public WrappedStream(InputStream urlStream) {
    this.urlStream = urlStream;
    this.pipedStream = new PipedOutputStream();
}

/**
 * return a fresh InputStream to re-read the data
 */
public InputStream getReReadStream() throws IOException {
    return new PipedInputStream(pipedStream);
}
@Override
public int available() throws IOException {
    return urlStream.available();
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    urlStream.close();
}

@Override
public void mark(int readlimit) {
    urlStream.mark(readlimit);
}

@Override
public boolean markSupported() {
    return urlStream.markSupported();
}

@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
    int b = urlStream.read();
    pipedStream.write(b);
    return b;
}

@Override
public int read(byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
    int l = urlStream.read(buffer);
    pipedStream.write(buffer);
    return l;
}

@Override
public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
    int l = urlStream.read(buffer, offset, length);
    pipedStream.write(buffer, offset, length);
    return l;
}

@Override
public void reset() throws IOException {
    urlStream.reset();
}

@Override
//bytes skipped must available on the re-read stream so we read and write them.
public long skip(long byteCount) throws IOException {
    long bytesToSkip = byteCount;
    long skippedBytes = 0;
//ugly trick required to not loosing bytes if we ever skip more than Integer.MAX_VALUE bytes
    while(bytesToSkip>Integer.MAX_VALUE){
        _skip(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        bytesToSkip -=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        skippedBytes +=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    byte[] b = new byte[(int)bytesToSkip];
    skippedBytes += read(b);
    return skippedBytes;
}

private int _skip(int byteCount) throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[(int)byteCount];
    return read(b);
}
}
```

Please note that I didn't test this code. This is just to give you some ideas on how to solve your problem.

Another point: even if this code never create a huge bitmap, the whole stream will be kept in memory until the scaled Bitmap is build.

Answer (score 0):

here is the method to download bitmap from server with less code you can fulfill your requirement

```
Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url)
        {
            Bitmap image = null;
            InputStream in = null;
            try
                {
                    in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    opts.inSampleSize = 2;
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(in),null,opts);
                    in.close();
                }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return image;
        }
```

in the above code we use 
    opts.inSampleSize = 2;
it means the bitmap will be reduced to half size of its original size to avoid memory exception we have to do this if we are loading lot of images

some other class used in it

```
        static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream
        {
            public FlushedInputStream( InputStream inputStream )
                {
                    super(inputStream);
                }

            @Override
            public long skip(long n) throws IOException
                {
                    long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
                    while (totalBytesSkipped < n)
                        {
                            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
                            if (bytesSkipped == 0L)
                                {
                                    int byte1 = read();
                                    if (byte1 < 0)
                                        {
                                            break; // we reached EOF
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                                        }
                                }
                            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
                        }
                    return totalBytesSkipped;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use below code for download and display image into imageview.

```
public class image extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage("http://www.gophoto.it/view.php?i=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2LTvCCufBKc/T3L3KgcTj2I/AAAAAAAABbQ/Ki60e1LU9sE/s1600/Sachin%2BTendulkar.png");
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }

    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```